# How to specify which version of nuget.exe to use with self-hosted agent in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I'm running self-hosted agent and `NuGetToolInstaller` was always throwing an error `ERR:unable to get local issuer certificate`.

I found a fix-hack [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/606419/nugettoolinstaller-fails-errunable-to-get-local-is.html?childToView=613554#comment-613554). Just to download needed `nuget.exe` version to the machine, add it to Environment Variables and remove `NuGetToolInstaller` at all. It fixed the issue, but today I understood that it's not really so.

Currently, I have `nuget.exe version 5.6.0` so I thought self-hosted agent uses it but...

While running `Initialize Job` Azure downloads NuGetCommand

[image]

I found the location and can see that it downloads three different versions of `nuget.exe`

[image]

And it always uses `4.1.0` for any NuGetCommand.

[image]

How can I specify which version of NuGet to use without `NuGetToolInstaller`?

Or how to make `Initialize Job` **not** downloading any `nuget.exe` and just use that one available in the system?

For testing I deleted everything from the `yaml` and it looks like this:

```
trigger:
- master
pool:
  name: somePool    
jobs:
- job: someJob  
  variables:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'  
  steps:
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the pipeline log, it seems nuget task use v4.1 by default:

[image]

If you don't want to use `NuGetToolInstaller` task, one workaround is replacing the nuget.exe with the version you want to use in the `{agent work folder}\_tool\NuGet\4.1.0\x64` folder.

Comment: It works, but it's a hack. If no one will come up with some reals config then I'll mark this as a correct one.